# How can I get the correct facebook page id from a page-tab application using facebook php sdk v4?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to write a Facebook-tab application that can be modified to the page that will add it. So I am trying to find a way to access the parent page id from my Facebook tab.

Does anyone know a way to do that using Facebook PHP sdk v4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use FacebookPageTabHelper and the getPageID() method. First hit Googling gives me https://gist.github.com/niraj-shah/fcd17411def017e3aefc which looks like a good start for you